# SMOTE for logistic regression model had a worse result compared to original?

Tags: regression, logistic, smote

Not sure why using more sample from SMOTE() could lower the overall accuracy:

```
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.4)

X, y = over.fit_resample(X, y)

counter = Counter(y)

print(counter)
```

Counter({'no': 19548, 'yes': 7819})

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Instantiate the logistic regression classifier: logreg
logreg = LogisticRegression()
# Fit it to the training data
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
# Compute and print the confusion matrix and classification report
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

[[3616  293]
[ 964  601]]
precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
      no       0.79      0.93      0.85      3909
     yes       0.67      0.38      0.49      1565

accuracy                           0.77      5474
```

macro avg       0.73      0.65      0.67      5474
weighted avg       0.76      0.77      0.75      5474

the original result without SMOTE()
[[3897   41]
[ 514   48]]
precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
      no       0.88      0.99      0.93      3938
     yes       0.54      0.09      0.15       562

accuracy                           0.88      4500
```

macro avg       0.71      0.54      0.54      4500
weighted avg       0.84      0.88      0.84      4500

(I used get_dummies and MinMaxScaler)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective of SMOTE is to oversample the minority class with some synthetic data and undersample the majority class, followed by using those samples in a model.

This is good if you are more concerned about mislabeling the minority class as the majority class than vice-versa. However, if *accuracy* is all you are concerned with—as in, the % labeled correctly—then most of the value of that metric is going to come from labeling the majority class, in which case I would not recommend SMOTE.

It may be possible that SMOTE's synthetic data creation can reduce some overfitting on the minority class to improve accuracy, but I think that would be overshadowed by changing the objective from equal-weighting of classes to biasing more towards the minority class.

Without seeing some additional statistics, it could be that your features or model type are not well-suited for the problem, either. e.g., a sparse, minority-class ring closely around a dense, majority-class ring/circle.

Comment: Thanks, Max! SMOTE do have increased recall in the minor group I think, but did not help with the F1 score or accuracy.